# Trying to download FT historical data with Python - can anyone please solve this error?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Using a great answer from RJ Adriaansen for this task:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import time

#create list of annual dates for the past 100 years starting from today
datelist = pd.date_range(end=datetime.now(),periods=100,freq=pd.DateOffset(years=1))[::-1].strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
#create empty df
df = pd.DataFrame(None, columns=['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume'])

#not sure when the historical data starts, so let's wrap it in a while loop
while True:
    for end, start in zip(datelist, datelist[1:]):
        try:
            r = requests.get(f'https://markets.ft.com/data/equities/ajax/get-historical-prices?startDate={start}&endDate={end}&symbol=535700333').json()
            df_temp = pd.read_html('<table>'+r['html']+'</table>')[0]
            df_temp.columns=['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume']
            df = df.append(df_temp)
            time.sleep(2)
        except:
            break
    break
```

But I'm getting a syntax error

```
File "Scrape.py", line 16
r = requests.get(f'https://markets.ft.com/data/equities/ajax/get-historical-prices?startDate={start}&endDate={end}&symbol=535700333').json()
```

If I remove `f` from

```
r = requests.get(f'https://markets.ft.com/data/equities/ajax/get-historical-prices?startDate={start}&endDate={end}&symbol=535700333').json()
```

code runs but no output

As you might well have guessed my knowledge of Python is pitiful - can anyone please help?
Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please [edit] your question and format your code as code, and make a [mcve] by including the full error traceback so that we can better understand the issue

Comment: What version of python are you running? If lower than 3.6 you won't be able to use f strings

Answer (score 1):

`pd.read_html()` gives error `no table found`. So it change to

```
df_temp = pd.read_html('<table>'+r['html']+'<table>')[0]
```

which I think was actually intended.

Also, `pd.Dataframe.append()` is deprecated, so use `concat` instead

```
df = pd.concat([df, df_temp], ignore_index=True)
```

And `periods=100` will probably give you error, so decrease it to 5 or so. And, remove `while` loop and `try/except` as well to see if other error exists.

Comment: Thank you guys, for the comments - I'm running Python 2.7.15 on Linux Mint  19.3 Cinnamon 4.4.5 - I'll work on updating that and let you know progress ....